# Spring Boot SSL works only on RestController Contstructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rpc

Since I'm moving old architecture to a new Spring Boot solution I'm implementing the calls through @RestController.

Now, the FE needs to pass data to my @RestController which handles it, and make an old RPC-call to an old SoapWs.

The Rpc Ws-Endpoint uses Https, and needs a certificate.
So I've put everything in the Keystore and set the System.Properties accordingly.
Now the interesting part.
If I define the System properties in main spring boot Application Startup Class:

```
    @Component
    public class ApplicationStartup 
    implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {


      @Override
      public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/cert/clientkeystore.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/cert/clientkeystore.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");

      }
```

I can see them in the @RestController. I've checked them through System.getProperties(...) method and they are where they're supposed to be.
But the call to remote-rpc ws gives Handshake failure.

If set variables in the @RestController constructor....it works!
That's the only change.
I'm astonished, no clues at all.

Comment: isn't there a typo? C:/ prefix is missing from trustStore path

Comment: No it's just me amending things to publish code. Anyways corrected...thanks!

Comment: It is possible that ApplicationReadyEvent  is too late to register such values, as SSLContext might already be initialized. Try putting them in @PostConstruct of the component.

Comment: Yep that's more or less my "constructor approach". But other than specify every time I build the bean, I would fine-grained control the keystore.on a specific call.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that. Why do you want to be able to change the trustStore for every call? Anyways, you can create multiple instances of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html, and depending on what library you use for the remote call, inject an instance into that.

Comment: E.g. `SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(
                        storeUrl, password).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = 
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();`

Comment: That's not the right approach. I'm on RPC scenario, pls read here: http://www.xyzws.com/scdjws/SGS34/8
Basically my question is, WHY need to set security properties in every bean I need that rpc call and NOT once for entire project?
Basically fine-grained security it's okay, maybe redundant but I can choose at least.
But here I'm moving without knowing why this thing happen.

Comment: Still need to test but maybe that PostConstruct\Constructor property set could be enough for entire project by the way...but do I really need to put that on a bean?

Comment: Oh, I get it, we misunderstood each other it seems. You do not need to put it in every bean, just in the ApplicationStartup bean, maybe in a @PostConstruct (or in constructor), and remove it from everywhere else. The `setProperty` sets the property for the jvm the application runs in, so your beans should 'see them'. You should just put it in a place that runs before default ssl context gets initialized.